# Addin - this workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I have selected a certain number of addins in Excel to be loaded on startup but I get this error when I open Excel:

> This workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if an addin (A1) references another addin (A2) but A1 is loaded *before* A2.

The easiest way to define the order in which the addins are loaded is to edit the registry with `regedit`.

First of all, close Excel!

Then go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/16.0/Excel/Options` (for Excel 2016 - you need to adapt the path for other versions).

The addins that are loaded when Excel starts are indicated in the `OPEN`, `OPEN1`, `OPEN2` etc. keys.

If you want the addin currently in `OPEN3` to load before the addin currently in `OPEN2`, simply rename:

- `OPEN2` into `OPEN_TEMP`
- `OPEN3` into `OPEN2`
- and finally `OPEN_TEMP` into `OPEN3`

Comment: This is a good solution and solved the annoyance. Once you identify the Addin being referenced, that must be loaded before the addins which have a reference to it. I wonder, Is there a way to change open order without going into registry?